# White noise residuals but not fits as normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, forecasting, white-noise

I'm having problems with forecast and SARIMA.

Got successfull estimation when looking to white noise residuals, but they don't fit as a normal distribution.

```
    Box-Ljung test

data:  residuals(Receita_futura)
X-squared = 0.01207, df = 1, p-value = 0.9125

    Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  Receita_futura$residuals
W = 0.5978, p-value < 2.2e-16

    Jarque Bera Test

data:  Receita_futura$residuals
X-squared = 23301, df = 2, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

**Can I assume that "peak" on my residuals is the whole problem on my prediction? **

Here the Results from `checkresiduals` on *"forecast"* package

[image: Results from <code>checkresiduals</code> on *"forecast"* package]

and the prediction

[image]

Comment: Please post your original data set.  I have never seen a more complicated model.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzN3gZlyRQWOcXZrblNYLWxnRjg/view?usp=sharing
One thing is wrong on the plots: time series starts on 1999, so the outlier is on 2010 sep. btw this time series is the original "incomes from brazilian government" 
Outlier here is from a financial capitalization movement of Petrobras. when it becomes the the fourth largest in world. So, no error on data. 
Forget about the ARIMA parameters already shown.

Comment: also check [this](https://otexts.com/fpp2/residuals.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assume that this peak at the end of 2014 is your *whole* problem, but it is definitely the *biggest* problem you can see right now. You can even see it in the original plot of your data, before fitting any models.

You should:

1. Include a regressor to deal with what appears to be an additive outlier at that point.
2. Re-evaluate the best ARIMA model (it may change).
3. Look at the diagnostics again.

Note that there are more general procedures for iteratively finding these irregularities, but in this case this one is so obvious that you should probably include it from the start, especially if you have sufficient domain knowledge that you can explain what happened to make that point different.